# PHP - Fetch all dates between two dynamic UNIX timestamps

Tags: php, laravel, date

I want to get all the dates between two given specific dates which will be changing dynamically according to the user requirements.

This works fine for me :

```
$begin = new DateTime( '2018-07-01' ); 
$end = new DateTime( '2018-08-10' );
$end = $end->modify( '+1 day' ); 
$interval = new DateInterval('P1D');
$daterange = new DatePeriod($begin, $interval ,$end);

$dates = [];

foreach($daterange as $date){
    array_push($dates,$date->format('Y-m-d'));
}

return $dates;
```

But this gives me NULL array when I insert dates dynamically. For example,

```
$begin = new DateTime($request->date1); 
$end = new DateTime(today()); 
$interval = new DateInterval('P1D');
$daterange = new DatePeriod($begin, $interval ,$end);

$dates = [];

foreach($daterange as $date){
    array_push($dates,$date->format('Y-m-d'));
}

return dates;
```

I have tried many inputs like storing today's date in a variable, changing it's format and then using that variable as an input. I tried changing date variable to string using (string) function and also I have used Carbon classes for dates, but somehow I am making mistake using DateTime, DateInterval and DatePeriod as I don't know the basics of them.

I need to get all the dates between two specific dates for charts in my admin panel.

Comment: check `$request->date1` format and debug code like `echo $begin` & `echo $end`

Comment: Sir, I tried this  $present = Carbon::now()->toDateString(); and then $begin = new DateTime( $present ); but I am getting this error {msg: "Object of class DateTime could not be converted to string 32", status: 0} and even without toDateString function, I am getting the same error.

Comment: if you got empty array it may be because your interval is greater than the gap between your start date and your end date...You need to check wether or not $start!==$end and $end-$start>Interval...

Comment: I checked it, $interval is fine. but still I am getting null array

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally got the solution for this question. It worked by converting the dates to UNIX timestamp. Here's the code, how it worked:

```
$date_from = "2018-07-01";   
$date_from = strtotime($date_from); // Convert date to a UNIX timestamp  

// Specify the end date. This date can be any English textual format  
$date_to = strtotime(today()); // Convert date to a UNIX timestamp  

$dates = [];

// Loop from the start date to end date and output all dates inbetween  
for ($i=$date_from; $i<=$date_to; $i+=86400) {  
    array_push($dates,date("Y-m-d", $i));  
}

return $dates;
```

[Here](http://biostall.com/get-a-list-of-dates-between-two-dates-with-php/) is the reference where I found this solution, hope this helps others too.